# Fill all entries between two specified values

Tags: r

I have a long vector, thousands of entries, which has elements 0, 1, 2 in it sporadically. 0 means "no signal", 1 means "signal on", and 2 means "signal off". I am trying to find the runs from 1 to the next occurrence of 2 and fill the space with 1s. I also need to do the same thing between a 2 and the next occurrence of 1 but fill the space with 0s.

I currently have a solution for this issue using loops but it's slow and incredibly inefficient:

example vector:
`exp = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,2,0,1,0,2)`

desired result:
`1,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,1,1,2`

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `rle` & `shift` from the **data.table**-package in the following way:

```
library(data.table)

# create the run-length object
rl <- rle(x)

# create indexes of the spots in the run-length object that need to be replaced
idx1 <- rl$values == 0 & shift(rl$values, fill = 0) == 1 & shift(rl$values, fill = 0, type = 'lead') %in% 1:2
idx0 <- rl$values == 2 & shift(rl$values, fill = 0) == 0 & shift(rl$values, fill = 2, type = 'lead') %in% 0:1

# replace these values
rl$values[idx1] <- 1
rl$values[idx0] <- 0
```

Now you will get the desired result by using `inverse.rle`:

```
> inverse.rle(rl)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 1 1 2
```

As an alternative for the `shift`-function, you could also use the `lag` and `lead` functions from **dplyr**.

---

If you want to assess the speed of both approaches, the `microbenchmark`-package is a useful tool. Below you'll find 3 benchmarks, each for a different vector size:

```
# create functions for both approaches
jaap <- function(x) {
  rl <- rle(x)

  idx1 <- rl$values == 0 & shift(rl$values, fill = 0) == 1 & shift(rl$values, fill = 0, type = 'lead') %in% 1:2
  idx0 <- rl$values == 2 & shift(rl$values, fill = 0) == 0 & shift(rl$values, fill = 2, type = 'lead') %in% 0:1

  rl$values[idx1] <- 1
  rl$values[idx0] <- 0

  inverse.rle(rl)
}

john <- function(x) {
  Reduce(f, x, 0, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
}
```

Execute the benchmarks:

```
# benchmark on the original data

> microbenchmark(jaap(x), john(x), times = 100)
Unit: microseconds
    expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval cld
 jaap(x) 58.766 61.2355 67.99861 63.8755 72.147 143.841   100   b
 john(x) 13.684 14.3175 18.71585 15.7580 23.902  50.705   100  a 

# benchmark on a somewhat larger vector

> x2 <- rep(x, 10)
> microbenchmark(jaap(x2), john(x2), times = 100)
Unit: microseconds
     expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval cld
 jaap(x2)  69.778  72.802  84.46945  76.9675  87.3015 184.666   100  a 
 john(x2) 116.858 121.058 127.64275 126.1615 130.4515 223.303   100   b

# benchmark on a very larger vector

> x3 <- rep(x, 1e6)
> microbenchmark(jaap(x3), john(x3), times = 20)
Unit: seconds
     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 jaap(x3)  1.30326  1.337878  1.389187  1.391279  1.425186  1.556887    20  a 
 john(x3) 10.51349 10.616632 10.689535 10.670808 10.761191 10.918953    20   b
```

From this you can conclude that the `rle`-approach has an advantage when applied to vectors that are larger than 100 elements (which is probably nearly always).

Comment: PERFECT! Owe you a beer

Comment: This is quite nice. I suspected that `rle` was relevant but couldn't work out just how.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `Reduce` with the following function:

```
f <- function(x,y){
  if(x == 1){
    if(y == 2) 2 else 1
  }else{
    if(y == 1) 1 else 0
  }
}
```

Then:

```
> x <- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,2,0,1,0,2)
> Reduce(f, x, 0, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 1 1 2
```

Comment: Nice alternative, but the resulting vector is not of the same length. You need to add `[-1]` to `Reduce`-call to remove the extra 1 at the start (i.e.: `Reduce(f, x, 1, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]`).

Comment: Another point: imo you need to use `0` in the `Reduce`-call for cases when a vector starts with a zero. I've taken the liberty to fix that, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Jaap OP's didn't really specify what should happen in that case. Sometimes 0 becomes 1 and sometimes it stays 0, based on current state. My original solution defaulted to "signal on" at the beginning, your edit in effect defaults to treating the initial signal as off. Arguably "off" is a more natural default than "on", so I am fine with your edit.

Comment: It's fairly insignificant re: the initial value. Thank you @JohnColeman for the alternative! It will come down to speed in the end which I'm not yet able to test. As always, I love these sorts of answers because it's a new challenge to make intuitive the solution and not just copy.

Thank you both very much!